# if a cell contains a certain string delete the cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, rows, contains

In my vba code below right now the code searches for a string right now is red. What I would like to do is when the cell contains red it is also delete. Right now the cell can only contain red for it to be deleted.

```
    Sub collapse_columns()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 4
        collapse_column x
    Next
End Sub


Sub collapse_column(column_number As Integer)

    Dim row As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim last_row As Long
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' work on the active sheet
    'Set s = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'work on a specific sheet
    
    last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(s.Rows.Count, column_number).End(xlUp).row
    
    Dim colors_to_delete As String
    colors_to_delete = ",red," ' be sure to keep the leading and trailing commas
    
    For row = last_row To 1 Step -1
      If InStr(1, colors_to_delete, "," & Cells(row, column_number).Value & ",") > 0 Then Cells(row, column_number).Delete xlUp
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of what these cells values look like. I feel like I'm looking at copy/paste code that you don't understand coupled with a vague description of what your sheet might look like. If the cell contains only `"red"` then just do `If Cells(row, column_number).value = colors_to_delete`.

Comment: @JNevill the reason for my question if what if its light red. I still want the whole cell deleted. right now the code i have above does not delete the whole block only if its just red.

Comment: It's important that you share some sample of the cells that you are wanting to delete. Would you want to delete a cell with the value `unsecured`, `predation`, `orange-red`, or `tired`? Or is the values in your cells comma delimited? If that's the case then we probably care about `red,`, `,red,` and `,red` (as an example). Or we may want to do something cleaner like `For Each color In split(Cells(row, column_number).value, ',')`...

Comment: @JNevill I would be trying to delete cells like orange red. To make it more simple with the defensive programming. I want to delete any cells with red and spaces on the left side of the r and the right side of the d only.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is space delimited then you can try the following:

```
Sub collapse_column(column_number As Integer)

    Dim row As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim last_row As Long
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' work on the active sheet
    'Set s = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'work on a specific sheet
    
    last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(s.Rows.Count, column_number).End(xlUp).row
    
    Dim colors_to_delete As String
    colors_to_delete = "red" 
    
    For row = last_row To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(row, column_number).Value, " " & colors_to_delete & " ") > 0 Then Cells(row, column_number).Delete xlUp
    Next
    
End Sub
```

The only issue with this is that it requires a space to become both before AND after your `red` string. So cells with values like `orange red` won't get deleted as there is no trailing space. Instead, splitting the cells by a space into an array of colors/words and then searching for `red` in that array would give better results:

```
Sub collapse_column(column_number As Integer)

    Dim row As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim last_row As Long
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' work on the active sheet
    'Set s = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'work on a specific sheet
    
    last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(s.Rows.Count, column_number).End(xlUp).row
    
    Dim colors_to_delete As String
    colors_to_delete = "red" 
    
    For row = last_row To 1 Step -1
         For Each color In Split(Cells(row, column_number).Value, " ")
              If InStr(1, Cells(row, column_number).Value, colors_to_delete) > 0 Then 
                   Cells(row, column_number).Delete xlUp
                   Exit For 
         Next color
    Next row
    
End Sub
```

With this you will delete cells/rows that fit any of the following `orange red`, `red`, `red orange`, `orange red blue`.

Comment: I am getting a runtime error at Sub collapse_column(column_number As Integer) compile error: Variable required - cant assign to this expression